# How can I switch the Mac Version MonoDevelop from German to English?

Tags: macos, mono-framework, monodevelop

I just installed MonoDevelop on my mac, and I like it. But I don't like the German translation and I can't find any place in the menus where I could change the interface language.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac, applications try to follow the system wide language preference provided that they have the corresponding localization. So, the easiest way to change the menu language in MonoDevelop **without** changing the system preferences is to remove or rename the German localization so that the app will fall back to using the US menus.

To do this: control-click the icon for the MonoDevelop application and choose "Show Package Contents". Then navigate to the Resources subdirectory, find German.lproj (or something similar - I don't have MonoDevelop) and rename it. This will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run the program with the appropriate environment variables to tell gettext which translation to load/use. [Here is some documentation on gettext environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/Locale-Environment-Variables.html).

LANGUAGE=en_US would be a good place to start, unfortunately I don't have an OSX machine to verify, let us know what works.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me was using the following AppleScript and making it an applet:

do shell script "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 open /Applications/MonoDevelop.app"

This took me two hours to find this out :-(

-Matthias

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop 2.4 has an option in Preferences to override the GUI language.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodevelop-list/2008-May/007720.html) mail from Miguel, you have to change the LANG environment variable LANG to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. I'm not familiar with Mac, but the linux terminal way would be prepending `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` exactly before the command which changes this variable for the executing application.

Answer (score 0):

cefstat is right, the actual path is Contents/MacOS/share/locale/**